# How to set up a new user in a linux server to work with Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have added a new user in a linux server.

While I can run simple python script, the new user get errors to import package that I can upload.

For instance

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

returns

```
no module named 'matplotlib'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you probably did :

```
pip install --user matplotlib
```

to install matplotlib on your side.

You have multiple solutions, here a non-exhaustive one (docker would be probably overkilled for that purpose imo) ordered from the worse to the best :

- Install packages for everyone and avoid using --user when using pip
- Create a requirements.txt with all the needed package names and all your users can do `pip install -r requirements.txt --user`
- Create a requirements.txt and use virtual environments (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html or https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can be for multiple reasons.

## matplotlib installed as user

If you installed matplotlib with `pip install --user package` in a different user account. Don't expect another user to have that package available, it won't happen.

Install the package with `pip install package` to be available system wide, for all users.

*Note. Depending on your specific setup you may need elevated permissions.*

## matplotlib is installed in different python version

Irrespectively of how you installed the package (see above), you might have installed it in a different version than the one you're trying to run.

To be sure you can import the package, as in `python -m package`, use `python -m pip install package`. This will ensure the same python interpreter is used to install as is used to execute.

## Better approaches

### one more standard approach

Learn and use virtual environments. They are made to handle a python interpreter installation per project, rather than per system. Allowing you to keep dependent packages isolated from your system's python packages.

### one slightly more advance approach

I'll use the opportunity to share a little Makefile that handles that crap for me. Manages a virtual environment in the development folder, and keeps it up to date to with whatever packages are set in `requirements.txt`.

Invoking `make test` is sufficient to run the test suite (or any other thing you may configure) in an environment with the correct packages.

```sh
.PHONY: test

# directory to store virtual environment
VENV_NAME=venv

# python runtime version
PYTHON_VER=3.7

# python executble
PYTHON=${VENV_NAME}/bin/python${PYTHON_VER}

# pip requirements file
REQUIREMENTS=requirements.txt

venv:           ## Recreates the virtual environment if needed.
venv: $(VENV_NAME)/bin/activate
$(VENV_NAME)/bin/activate: ${REQUIREMENTS}
    test -d $(VENV_NAME) || virtualenv -p python${PYTHON_VER} $(VENV_NAME)
    ${PYTHON} -m pip install -U pip
    ${PYTHON} -m pip install -r ${REQUIREMENTS}
    touch $@

test:           ## Runs the test suite.
test: venv
    $(PYTHON) -m pytest tests
```